# how to change the column name dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In a database there are two tables. 
Table1 and Table2

Table1:

```
   column1    column2    column3

    271          211       111

    301          333        333
```

Table2:

```
  ColumnNo   Value  Desc

  1           271   aaa

  3           111    bbb

  2           211    ccc

  2           333    ddd

  1           301     eee
```

Here columnNo refers to the 1st table>> 1=Column1,2=column2,3=Column3.

so i have to update the 1st table column value with the Desc.
so the updated table1 will be

```
 column1   column2  column3

  aaa        ccc     bbb

  eee        ddd     ddd
```

like this.

As there are lots of column and value so how can i change the column name dynamically and update the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.column1 = T2.Desc,T1.column2 = T3.Desc,T1.column3 = T4.Desc
FROM Table1 T1 Inner Join Table2 T2 ON T1.column1 = T2.Value
               Inner Join Table2 T3 ON T1.column2 = T3.Value  
               Inner Join Table2 T4 ON T1.column3 = T4.Value
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43979/1)**

Comment: Thanks.
But there are 40 columns so is there any way to do this by using increment variable or something?